# Ethernet for Internet, WiFi for VSwitch

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, ethernet, hyper-v

I would like to:

1. Connect to the internet using the laptop ethernet port.
2. [Share the Wifi](http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/using-your-windows-8-wireless-connection-inside-hyper-v/#footer-bottom) on my laptop to a Hyper-V VSwitch and connect "physical" clients to the Hyper-V domain. (Tablets, laptops, et al.)

Currently, I am connected to the internet (and company domain) using the ethernet port and it's listed under the Windows 8 *Network and Sharing Centre*. However the Wifi, which is currently ON, isn't. I suspect this because it isn't connected to anything. Once I connect to one of the public Wifi hotspots near me, I can share the Wifi correctly however my internet and company domain drops out.

Is my desired outcome even possible?

Comment: I am not sure whether we can configure a wifi device as Access Point and a client at the same time. If you can achieve that, then you can use [Virtual Router] (http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) to achieve what you are planning.

Comment: To have a chance of this working, the wifi adapter must be put in ad-hoc mode to function as both a client and an access point. [This article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7) might help.

Comment: @Chandrasekar what do you mean by "wifi device"? Is that the laptop wifi, sharing the network, or the client device, with wifi? Thanks for the input so far though. I haven't cracked it yet but going to try it with VMWare Workstation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Share the ethernet controller to wifi using windows' internet sharing. You  r connections behind wifi should be NATted to the company's ethernet.
Connect the wifi controller as bridged device to the Domain controller.
Connect the clients to the ad hoc wifi. Add them to the domain.